# How to get 8 random unique elements from a string array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having a bit of trouble with some javascript code. Essentially what i need to do is get 8 unique elements from a 16 element string array.

I have this array

```
 biscuits = ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i', 'j', 'k','l','m','n','o','p']
```

I want to get a random 8 of those elements and print them out.

I know how to generate a random number in a range. What I'm struggling with is how to generate unique random numbers and then getting specific item out of the string array. If anybody could help I should be most grateful.

I'm not sure if I should use a nested for loop or check if the value is already in the array? I know this should be but for some reason I cannot do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will give you an array of unique newBiscuits that you can do what you want with:

```
biscuits = ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i', 'j', 'k','l','m','n','o','p'];
newBiscuits=new Array();
items=16;
while(newBiscuits.length<8) {
    newBiscuits.push(biscuits.splice(parseInt(Math.random()*items), 1));
    items--;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could copy your array, and remove the generated value when you pick it. 
So next time you randomly pick an element, you're unable to pick the same one again.
This requires your array to consist only of unique elements (no duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do that. One way:

- make a copy of the array
- generate random number
- remove the chosen element from the array
- generate a new number based on new array length
  ...
  i think you get the idea?